# Can HBr add to a non-sp2 hybridized carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image][image]

Does this reaction make sense? Mechanistically speaking, it does not for me. Is this a special case, or just a typo in the book?

Comment: I don't believe it's a typo. Can you describe the mechanism as you see it?

Comment: I think I got it. There is a carbocation rearrangement. Basically the H can produce two secondary carbocations. One of those secondary carbocations can do a 1,2-hydride shift, which produces a tertiary carbocation. This carbocation, being tertiary, will react much faster, resulting in being in the major product.

Comment: Excellent. You should write that up as an answer and answer your own question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a carbocation rearrangement. Basically, the H can produce two secondary carbocations. One of those secondary carbocations can do a 1,2-hydride shift, which produces a tertiary carbocation. This carbocation, being tertiary, will react much faster, resulting in being in the major product. So, yes, HBr can add to a non-sp2 carbon.

Comment: Most likely what happens is that the secondary carbocation rearranges to the tertiary carbocation much faster than bromide can attack the secondary carbocation. The tertiary carbocation is more stable than the secondary carbocation, so all else being equal, the secondary carbocation will react faster than the tertiary carbocation. And that's exactly what we see in this case, except that the reaction isn't addition of a nucleophile, it's the 1,2-hydride shift.

Comment: Jerepierre, I think you meant "tertiary carbocation will react faster"

Comment: No, I meant that the secondary carbocation will react faster... It's less stable, so it should react faster. The reason the tertiary bromide is observed as the product here is because the secondary carbocation rearranges to the tertiary carbocation faster than the nucleophilic attack.